# Formatação em postagens com intenção de aumentar o destaque

Tags: debate, suporte, comportamento, formatação

Me deparei com os seguintes posts hoje:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/71538/3635
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/71539/3635

Eu editei, mas o conforme conversei com o autor, ele me disse que faz uso de `###` para evidenciar as postagens e disse que faria o rollback, porém ambos concordamos em abrir esta discussão aqui.

O uso de:

```
###texto de exemplo
```

Te dá esta saída:

> #### texto de exemplo

Que equivale a:

```
<h3>texto de exemplo</h3>
```

Em outras palavras, o autor coloca a postagem toda como se fosse um título. Não estou julgando ele, apenas pensando nas boas práticas.

Notei que muitas pessoas usam `**text**` e CAIXA-ALTA (todas letras em maiúsculo) em longas frases sem necessidade com o mesmo objetivo, tornar algo mais evidente para quem ler a postagem.

Esta prática me parece "aceitável" (negrito, caixa-alta e `###`), mas realmente isto não me parece algo útil para a comunidade e eu realmente acho que a marcação deve ser usada corretamente para o que ela é destinada, além de achar que este tipo de prática, quando usada em *excesso* polui a visualização.

Devo editar e orientar o autor quando encontrar práticas semelhantes? (Ou não)

Comment: Fico meio na dúvida do que dizer sobre isto...

Answer (score 8):

Conforme nossa discussão no chat, vou deixar claro minha posição sobre isso. Apenas tenho utilizado `###` quando utilizo o *snippet*, justamente pelo fato de frases de 1 linha ficarem com destaque nenhum. Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É pessoal, mas pelo menos pra mim aquela última linha passa quase despercebida. E que fique claro que eu **não** sou a favor de usar `###` se a resposta tiver somente texto (sem precisar de títulos) ou for muito curta.

Comment: +1  para evidenciar o seu argumento, obrigado

Comment: Eu entendo, e até concordo, que o texto fica sem destaque numa resposta com pouco texto e muito código. Mas ainda assim acho que não justifica o uso de `#`s. O destaque criado pela marcação destoa bem do resto, e chama atenção demais.

Comment: @Gabe Vou tentar outras alternativas nas futuras respostas, não vou dar rollback nas respostas linkadas pra não atrapalhar nesta pergunta.

Answer (score 4):

Esse tipo de formatação realmente prejudica a harmonia e resulta em concorrência com o título da questão. Na prática, outras respostas podem perder "valor" em decorrência da alta visibilidade da resposta, como se dissesse *"Ei! Atenção para esta resposta!"*. Particularmente, sou contra e creio que nem o **negrito** é necessário, não há necessidade em destacar algo que não é tópico, título ou de muita importância.

> Com o plugin [jsPDF](http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/) é possível realizar esse procedimento.
>
> **Exemplo:**
>
> ```
> window.onload = function() {
>   var doc = new jsPDF();
>   doc.text(20, 20, 'Criando um cabeçalho.');
>   doc.setFont("courier");
>   doc.setFontType("normal");
>   doc.text(20, 30, 'Escrevendo num pdf.');
>   doc.save('Teste.pdf');
> }
> ```

Comment: Praticamente o meu ponto de vista +1

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento acho que o exemplo não ficou claro depois da sua formatação

Comment: @Math ao menos no meu entendimento "Quote" ou "citação" fazem referencia a outras "postagens", no caso não existe a postagem, mas faz citação a um exemplo. Ao menos até aonde entendo este é o motivo do uso das "citações", mas se achar que o pessoal não vai entender ou algo assim talvez seja melhor um rollback :) - talvez eu ainda esteja um pouco preso na "Era do Email" ;P

Comment: Bom, vamos ver o que outros usuários acham

Comment: @Math Ok, obrigado! Vai ver isto por chat, ou vai esperar alguém comentar? Sabe o que eu encontrei isto: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1905/3635

Answer (score 3):

Concordo com o [Maicon Carraro](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4087/maicon-carraro) que o snippet esconde um pouco o que vem depois, mas também concordo que utilizar a tag de título causa uma certa poluição visual, pois acaba tendo o efeito contrário ao do problema: Destaque demais para algo que não é um título.

Já que o problema é ocultar pequenas porções de texto após o snippet, por que não colocar este texto antes? É óbvio que a forma de fazer isso vai mudar caso a caso, mas para um dos exemplos dados acho que essa seria uma boa alternativa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim, a nada fica escondido depois do snippet. Se for uma resposta maior, uma boa maneira de deixar o texto mais agradável é organizar com títulos. Considerando as duas opções, não vejo porque escrever como título texto que deveria ser parte do corpo da resposta.

Segue abaixo um exemplo com títulos:

---

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer dolor nisi, vulputate vitae magna id, luctus lacinia nisi. Donec finibus dolor ut erat posuere tincidunt. Praesent aliquam sodales ex. Integer non commodo justo, sit amet vestibulum enim. In sem augue, dignissim ac venenatis et, aliquam vel dolor. Donec vitae neque id massa venenatis pellentesque nec eget arcu. Etiam in sagittis risus, eu sodales sem. Mauris tempus vehicula gravida.

#### Exemplo:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer dolor nisi, vulputate vitae magna id, luctus lacinia nisi.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Integer dolor nisi, vulputate vitae magna id, luctus lacinia nisi. 
Integer non commodo justo, sit amet vestibulum enim. 
In sem augue, dignissim ac venenatis et, aliquam vel dolor.
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Conclusão:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer dolor nisi, vulputate vitae magna id, luctus lacinia nisi. Donec finibus dolor ut erat posuere tincidunt. Praesent aliquam sodales ex. Integer non commodo justo, sit amet vestibulum enim. In sem augue, dignissim ac venenatis et, aliquam vel dolor.